# How to remove default sort order in Solr

Tags: java, solr, lucene

My solr query is:

```
( +comic.is_active:true +album.published_at:[* TO *] +( comic.id:(44917 42476) ) )
```

When I execute this query using Solr Admin, I want it to be in order as given. So above query will result 44917 as first record but instead it's producing 42476 as first record. I believe this is happening because it's sorting default by score but I simply don't want that. Please help me.

Comment: you can apply sorting by comic.id...in desc order

Comment: No. I want sort order to be as it is passed in query.

Comment: I don't think it is possible...

Comment: Hey, It was possible. Please see my ans

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to this problem:

Add Boost to every id in the query in sorted order, solr will result in order by that boost value